# Angular component property doesn't update upon change in referencing property

Tags: angular

I have the following component:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  {{ testCount }}<button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
</div>
```

With the following script:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  test = []
  testCount = this.test.length

  constructor() {

  }

  onClick() {
    this.test.push({})
    console.log(this.testCount)
  }
}
```

My issue is, that testCount doens't update in the HTML when i push a new element to the array it references. I'm sure there's a logical explanation behind this, and a possible solution concerning observables, but I can't find out the solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `testCount` variable won't be updated when you push new elements to the array everytime. It is being assigned the value `this.test.length` once at the beginning of the component lifecycle and that's it.

Controller

```js
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public test = [];
  testCount = this.test.length; // <-- assigned a value once at the beginning and never updated again

  constructor() { }

  onClick() {
    this.test.push({});
    console.log(this.testCount);  // <-- will log 0
  }
}
```

One quick way would be to use the `length` property directly in the template

Template

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  {{ test.length }}<button (mouseup)="onClick()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I updated this.test.length to `this.test.filter(x => x.y === 1).length` ? I wouldn't be able to use this statement inside the view, as it gives me an error

Comment: No you cannot use it in the template because [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is a property whereas [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method. It looks like you are new to Angular. I'd recommend you to go through https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces the concepts of Angular.

Comment: The fact that `filter` is a method is not the reason why it cannot be used in the template. The actual problem is that, in order to use `filter`, a callback must be provided, and creating a function in the template is forbidden. If an arrow function is defined in code, then `filter` could be called using that function as a callback.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to update this.testCount when you change the size of test.
If you want it to automatically update in the html, just use instead of trying to store the derived property in the component's state. Since it's easy enough to have a single source of truth for the this (test.length).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  {{ test.length }}<button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
</div>
```